# Make everything un-selectable while excluding one class

Tags: css, css-selectors

`<style>
    *:not(.selectable){
      -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
         -khtml-user-select: none;
           -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
                user-select: none;
                }
    .selectable{
        -webkit-touch-callout: auto!important;
          -webkit-user-select: auto!important;
           -khtml-user-select: auto!important;
             -moz-user-select: auto!important;
              -ms-user-select: auto!important;
                  user-select: auto!important;
                }
  </style>`

How do I make everything with `class="selectable"` select-able? Currently nothing is select-able using the cursor.

I would have thought that `!Important`  would override the css setting but it does not!

Comment: Just a quick tip: CSS stands for Cascade Style Sheet which means there is a hierarchy that defines which property must be applied to each element. Using !important ignores this classes and often times will do more harm than good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to add the rule .selectable. 
*:not(.selectable) should be sufficient to do your functionality.

But, Universal selectors and the :not() negation don't affect specificity Reference (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#Selector_Types),  So you need to add some element so the browser defaults can be overriden. What you can do is remove the universal selector and change it to html or body.

from

*:not(.selectable){}

to

```
body :not(.selectable){
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
     -khtml-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
   }
```

Fiddle to the same
https://jsfiddle.net/nuf7wfj4/